# intellij-idea - how to add custom build step to a module

Tags: ide, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ(8.x).  The build step require ant "ant" from outside to generate java files from .idl  files. This uses jacorb. I would like to avoid the step. Current work around is to call some scripts using "External Tools". This works, but I guess there may be a  better way to do it..

Is it possible to call custom build step from IntelliJ, so it  gets called we make or compile a module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the **Ant Panel** right click on a target and choose **Execute On** | **Before Compilation** or **After Compilation**.

If such option is not available in IDEA 8, try more recent version.